# getMap() + subsequent changes to sync map

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have an IMap, with Journal enabled.

Using a client (Hazelcast, or Jet), I would like to get the full map, and get all the subsequent updates to enrich the Map.

How could I achieve this?

If do a .getMap(), and then call getJournalMap() or .addEntryListener(), I am concerned with the possibility of missing updates in between the getMap() and addEntryListener() call.

Is there are more intuitive way to get full map+updates?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `getJournalMap()`? Is it Jet's `Sources.mapJournal(...)` ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `Continues Query Cache` feature of Hazelcast. Please see https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query-cache

Below is a sample usage from client

```
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

    QueryCacheConfig queryCacheConfig = new QueryCacheConfig("cache");
    PredicateConfig predicateConfig = new PredicateConfig().setImplementation((Predicate) entry -> true);
    queryCacheConfig.setPredicateConfig(predicateConfig);

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.addQueryCacheConfig("map", queryCacheConfig);

    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

    IMap<Object, Object> map = client.getMap("map");
    QueryCache<Object, Object> cache = map.getQueryCache("cache");
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Could I run .setPopulate(true) to the CQC, apply the EventListener, get the entire map, and all subsequent events would be handled by the listener?

Comment: Maybe I'd put some context in what I am trying to achieve... I'd like to build a websocket interface to my IMap.

At client connection, the server would response with the full snapshot of the Map, then all subsequent events.   The web client can then view the exact IMap in IMDG but appying the events into the first snapshot.

Comment: all you need to do is configure your map with query cache before creating the client. `QueryCache` will have the initial snapshot and subsequent updates to the actual map

Comment: Thanks!  Will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the event journal does not expose a public API for reading the event journal in Hazelcast IMDG. The event journal can be used to stream event data to Hazelcast Jet, so it should be used in conjunction with Hazelcast Jet. You can see some examples here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/tree/0.7-maintenance/event-journal

Comment: I can get the journal using Jet, but that'd only give me whatever is in the journal either START_FROM_OLDEST, or START_FROM_CURRENT.

How would I get the entire IMap, and start processing the journal from the point of last write to the IMap?